# ffmpeg - how to make a video to have no audio in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, audio, video, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -an -vcodec copy output_file.mp4
```

How can I change it to something like this below?

```
FFMpeg::fromDisk('local')
->open($filePath.$fileName)
->export()
->toDisk('local')
->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264'))
->save($converted);
```

Comment: That should be explained in the documentation for that class.

Comment: @Dormilich I can't understand that!!

Answer (score 0):

Its seems the package had 'Audio Mute' added to it in 2017 [HERE](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/pull/366)

Although it's not documented well (as far as I can see).

Having looked at the Class ([PR HERE](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/pull/366/commits/fb533ba82171e196a1547d75ce4b524e4a18034e)) you should be able to mute the audio by adding

```
->mute()
```

before

```
->save();
```

Comment: Thanks but it says it doesn't have this function!!